# How to solve connectivity problems when running parallel code in R, with the Parallelly package?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I did tests with the Parallel and Future packages, in which I run a function with different data, on my windows 10 machine. That is, this local cluster is made up of the cores of my processor, which is an i7. Specifically, what I did was, working with Parallel, the following:

```
"start <- proc.time()
cl <- makeCluster(cores)  #change the value of cores from 1 to 4.
outputs  <- parSapply(cl , vector , fun)
stopCluster(cl)
end <- proc.time()
print(end - start)"
```

That way I test parallelization and had no issues.
Now, I want to perform those same tests with a cluster made up of a VPS and my windows 10 machine.
In this case, the idea is that my windows 10 machine is the Master and that the VPS is the worker.
Now come the complications because I am not sure what to do, to achieve the aforementioned. And I can't establish communication between the machines.
I have a VPS, with Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bits), of which the provider gave me, on the one hand, the IP address, the user (root) and the password. Also, it has RStudio installed, therefore, I have the URL, username and password to start RStudio.
By the way, with sys.info () I get the nodename and user, which I don't know where to use them or if I'm using them right.

Here are the questions:

1.- How do I tell the cluster that my windows 10 machine is going to be the master and the VPS the worker ?.
Will it be something like the following? (working with Parallelly use, for example,

```
"makeClusterPSOCK):
workers <- c("localhost", "VPS’ip or the nodename")
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(workers, master=Sys.info()[["localhost’nodename"]], homogeneous = FALSE 
)"
```

2.- How do I do so that once my script is executed on my windows machine, these two machines can “establish communication”?
On the side of my windows machine I downloaded and installed puTTY, and I configured it, placing the IP address of the VPS, to access the VPS machine as a terminal. And with root and password I can use ssh commands remotely on the VPS. I understand, then, that I already have SSH installed on the VPS, right? (My knowledge is null in everything I am doing). And of course I already have ssh on my local machine.
3.- On the VPS side, what else do I have to do?
I don't need to start Rstudio or the VPS terminal, right?
Don't I have to do anything else with SSH?
4.- Of the arguments that I have below, what things will be wrong?
Is something missing?

```
"Sys.setenv(R_PARALLEL_PORT = 11000)
Sys.getenv("R_PARALLEL_PORT")
workers <- c("localhost", " VPS’ip or the nodename")
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK(workers, dryrun = TRUE, homogeneous = FALSE,
autoStop=TRUE, tries=10, delay=10, validate = TRUE, verbose = TRUE, master=Sys.info()[["nodename"]], timeout = 10, rscript= "Rscript", rscript_args = c ("- e", shQuote ('setwd ("/ ruta / a")')),rscript_libs= "*", methods= TRUE, useXDR = TRUE, renice = 2, rshcmd = c("<rstudio-ssh>", "<putty-plink>", "<ssh>"),rshopts = c("-i", "~/.ssh/my_private_key"), user="georges",revtunnel = TRUE, manual = TRUE, quiet = FALSE )"
```

OUTPUT IF I RUN THIS SCRIPT ON MY WINDOWS MACHINE: (In this output, I altered the ip and the name of the machines as a precaution)

```
Manually, start worker #1 on local machine ‘localhost’ with:
nice --adjustment=2 "Rscript" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods - e "setwd (\"/ ruta / a\")" -e ".libPaths(c(.libPaths()))" -e "workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()" MASTER=DESKTOP-XXXX PORT=11000 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=10 XDR=TRUE
Manually, (i) login into external machine ‘The VPS’ip’:
"C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\MSYS-S~1\ssh.exe" -R 11001:DESKTOP-XXXX:11000 -l luciano -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key ip de la VPS
and (ii) start worker #2 from there:
nice --adjustment=2 "Rscript" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods - e "setwd (\"/ ruta / a\")" -e ".libPaths(c(.libPaths()))" -e "workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()" MASTER=DESKTOP-XXXX PORT=11001 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=10 XDR=TRUE
Alternatively, start worker #2 from the local machine by combining both step in a single call:
"C:\PROGRA~1\RStudio\bin\MSYS-S~1\ssh.exe" -R 11001:DESKTOP-XXXX:11000 -l luciano -i ~/.ssh/my_private_key ip de la VPS "nice --adjustment=2 \"Rscript\" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods - e \"setwd (\\"/ ruta / a\\")\" -e \".libPaths(c(.libPaths()))\" -e \"workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()\" MASTER=DESKTOP-XXX PORT=11001 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=10 XDR=TRUE"
```

OUTPUT IF I RUN THIS SCRIPT ON MY WINDOWS MACHINE, BUT WITH DRYRUN = FALSE:

```
Manually, start worker #1 on local machine ‘localhost’ with:
nice --adjustment=2 "Rscript" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e "try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file=\"C:/Users/jlmal/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKkqxKO/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=1240.4d858365639.pid\")), silent = TRUE)" - e "setwd (\"/ ruta / a\")" -e ".libPaths(c(.libPaths()))" -e "workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()" MASTER=DESKTOP-xxx PORT=11000 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=10 XDR=TRUE
[local output] Waiting for worker #1 on ‘localhost’ to connect back
[local output] Detected a warning from socketConnection(): ‘problem in listening on this socket’
[local output] Failed 10 attempts with 10 seconds delay
Error in socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE, 
Failed to launch and connect to R worker on local machine ‘localhost’ from local machine ‘DESKTOP-xxxx’.
* The error produced by socketConnection() was: ‘connection cannot be opened
’* In addition, socketConnection() produced 1 warning(s):
- Warning #1: ‘problem in listening on this socket’
* The localhost socket connection that failed to connect to the R worker used port 11000 using a communication timeout of 10 seconds and a connection timeout of 120 seconds.
* Worker launch call: nice --adjustment=2 "Rscript" --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e "try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file=\"C:/Users/jlmal/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpKkqxKO/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=1240.4d858365639.pid\")), silent = TRUE)" - e "setwd (\"/ ruta / a\")" -e ".libPaths(c(.libPaths()))" -e "workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()" MASTER=DESKTOP-xxxx PORT=11000 OUT=/dev/null TIMEOUT=10 XD
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE, :
problem in listening on this socket
```

OUTPUT IF I RUN THIS SCRIPT ON THE VPS WITH DRYRUN = FALSE:

```
Manually, start worker #1 on local machine ‘localhost’ with:
  nice --adjustment=2 'Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/tmp/RtmpUZda3l/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=87021.153ed7f6392b.pid")), silent = TRUE)' - e 'setwd ("/ ruta / a")' -e '.libPaths(c(.libPaths()))' -e 'workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()' MASTER=vmi595655.contaboserver.net PORT=11000 OUT= TIMEOUT=10 XDR=TRUE

[local output] Waiting for worker #1 on ‘localhost’ to connect back
[local output] - Detected 'outfile=NULL': this will make the output from the background worker visible
[local output] Detected a warning from socketConnection(): ‘problem in listening on this socket’
Failed to launch and connect to R worker on local machine ‘localhost’ from local machine ‘vmi595655.contaboserver.net’.
 * The error produced by socketConnection() was: ‘cannot open the connection’
 * In addition, socketConnection() produced 1 warning(s):
   - Warning #1: ‘problem in listening on this socket’
 * The localhost socket connection that failed to connect to the R worker used port 11000 using a communication timeout of 10 seconds and a connection timeout of 120 seconds.
 * Worker launch call: nice --adjustment=2 'Rscript' --default-packages=datasets,utils,grDevices,graphics,stats,methods -e 'try(suppressWarnings(cat(Sys.getpid(),file="/tmp/RtmpUZda3l/worker.rank=1.parallelly.parent=87021.153ed49fb187c.pid")), silent = TRUE)' - e 'setwd ("/ ruta / a")' -e '.libPaths(c(.libPaths()))' -e 'workRSOCK <- tryCatch(parallel:::.slaveRSOCK, error=function(e) parallel:::.workRSOCK); workRSOCK()' MASTER=vmi595655.contaboserver.net PORT=11000 OUT= TIMEOUT=10 XDR=TRUE.
 * Failed to kill local worker because it's PID is could not be identified.
 * Troubleshooting suggestions:
   - Suggestion #1: Inspect the content of log file ‘/tmp/RtmpUZda3l/parallelly_makeClusterPSOCK_153ed2a229d7c.log’ for ‘<rstudio-ssh>’ ‘<putty-plink>’ ‘<ssh>’.

[local output] - waiting 10 seconds before trying again
[local output] - attempt #3 of 10
```

5.- If I want the VPS is the master and my local machine is the worker. Do I only make this change?

```
workers <- c ("localhost", "ip of the VPS or the nodename")
cl <- makeClusterPSOCK (workers, master = Sys.info () [["VPS nodename"]], homogeneous = FALSE)
```

Do I have to run the script from the Rstudio of the VPS? In that case, I don't have to run anything on my windows machine, do I? Just have it turned on ?.

Well, as you may have noticed, I have a long way to go from a conceptual and also practical point of view to carry out the task I want to achieve. But I would really appreciate if you could give me some light with this, to see if I can establish automatic communication between the machines and be able to run parallel R code.

In the following link there is information regarding the Parallelly package:
https://parallelly.futureverse.org/reference/makeClusterPSOCK.html

A big greeting
Luciano Maldonado

Comment: Hi (again). StackOverflow comment fields are too limited to resolve this, given the amount of things to be straightened out.  Please re-post on https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/future/discussions, I'll try to help you there instead.  I think it'll be quite a bit back and forth before we get it solved.  BTW, when posting, please include your `sessionInfo()` after doing `library(parallelly)`.

Comment: Perfect, I already did it Henrik. Thank you.